# Python change diction value from key in a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, object

I have successfully used recursion to find a key to a variable I want to change in an API reponse json.

The recursion returns the key the equivilant is like this:

```
obj_key = "obj['key1']['key2'][1]['key3'][4]['key4'][0]"
```

if I eval this:

```
eval(obj_key)
```

I get the value no problem.

Now I want to change the value if it isn't what I want it to be.  I can't figure this out and only get syntax error with every attempt .... all attempts are some form of:

```
eval(obj_key + ' = "my_new_value"')
```

I have slept on this one thinking it would come to me in a day or two (sometimes this works) but alas no epiphany for me.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't use `eval()`. That's  not what it's for. The string you are passing to `eval()` is executable Python code. Just put it (without the quotes) into an assignment statement to the right of `=`. And when you have convinced yourself that that will work, you will know how to change the value. Put the same bit of Python code to the left of the assignment operator `=`, instead of on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `eval`, you could keep a list of keys and a reference to the object. So instead of building a string

```
"obj['key1']['key2'][1]['key3'][4]['key4'][0]"
```

You'd just need

```
obj
```

and

```
['key1', 'key2', 1, 'key3', 4, 'key4', 0]
```

Which is probably easier to create and manipulate in your Python code.

To use this to get the value, you could write a function:

```
def my_get(obj, keys):  # TODO better name
    for key in keys:
        obj = obj[key]
    return obj
```

And to set a value:

```
def my_set(obj, keys, value):  # TODO better name
    last_obj = my_get(obj, keys[:-1])  # get the last dict or list, by skipping the last key
    last_obj[keys[-1]] = value  # now set the value using the last key
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was stuck in my head that I had to access the value through the full set of keys in one step.  So much so that it took me a few times stepping through your solution to see how it worked.  Fortunately for me my recursion find function was actually already returning a list and I was then building a string from it.  You saved me many many hours of struggle.

Answer (score 1):

Using exec instead of eval seems solving this problem:

```
eval("y=12") #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But replacing it with exec:

```
exec("y=12")
print(y) #12
```